# PL/PgSQL calling a function inside a loop giving error

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

The code bellow is giving error  on `w_add_ax_extra(1, 'k', 'v')` previously it was `w_add_ax_extra(some_id, kv.k, kv.v)` I changed it to `k, v` to reproduce the same error

```
declare
  kv record;
begin
  -- Lines skipped
  for kv in select * from (select (each(extras)).*) as f(k,v) loop
    raise notice 'key=%,value=%',kv.k,kv.v;
    w_add_ax_extra(1, 'k', 'v');
  end loop;
  -- Lines Skipped
end
```

I am getting Syntax Error but could not understand what I am missing

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "w_add_ax_extra"
LINE 1: w_add_ax_extra(1, 'k', 'v')
```

However If I do `dummy = w_add_ax_extra(1, 'k', 'v')` it works. Yes this function returns an integer. But I don't need to store it here. Is it mandatory to hold the return value ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the [fine manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-SQL-NORESULT):

> **39.5.2. Executing a Command With No Result**
>
> [...]
>
> Sometimes it is useful to evaluate an expression or SELECT query but discard the result, for example when *calling a function that has side-effects but no useful result value*. To do this in PL/pgSQL, use the PERFORM statement:
>
> ```
> PERFORM query;
> ```

Emphasis mine. You're not calling the function by saying something like `f();`, you need to `perform f();` or `select f() into ...;`:

```
for kv in select * from (select (each(extras)).*) as f(k,v) loop
    raise notice 'key=%,value=%',kv.k,kv.v;
    perform w_add_ax_extra(1, 'k', 'v');
end loop;
```

Comment: Thanks. It Fixed. But things are not clear :( I copy pasted that `f(k,v)` however only `f` works too. so I removed the `(k,v)` part. Oh! sorry it doesn't work without `(k,v)`